# Can Cuba (ruby framework) load HTML instead of HAML

Tags: html, ruby, haml, cuba

Currently working on a Cuba project, bunch of HAML file but for improving UI I still prefer pure HTML, but as I tried, It's seems very complicate to rebuild every thing to get rid of HAML.

Any clues?

Comment: This is too broad of a question. We need to know what you've tried, and what problems you've encountered. We can help you with those, but rewriting a project would take a book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a quick glance at the docs, Cuba can use any template [`tilt`](https://github.com/rtomayko/tilt) supports.  So if you want to switch to ERB (HTML-based template), you'd switch the template engine:

```
Cuba.settings[:render][:template_engine] = "erb"
```

And then re-write all of your view code in ERB.  Which seems like a lot of work compared to getting used to HAML, but alas.

There are tools to make HAML->ERB conversion easier, like [`herbalizer`](https://github.com/danchoi/herbalizer).